# MySQL, returning row using find_in_set is not working as expected

Tags: mysql, filter, find-in-set

I'm trying to run the following MySQL command:

```
SELECT ID, intervention_post_title, linked_article FROM wp_cpt_combined WHERE FIND_IN_SET (72, habitat_type)
```

Inside my database the column habitat_type (as this is a multiselect field) stores the values as"

```
id  habitat_type
1   [72, 74]
2   [70]
3   [71]
```

The above sql command returns no rows - what am I missing? I need to be able to pull back row 1 using find_in_set (72, habitat_type) or find_in_set (74, habitat_type) etc. Do I have to do a replace to remove the square brackets?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can use [`REPLACE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function to replace occurences of `[` and `]` with empty string.

Try the following:

```
SELECT 
  ID, 
  intervention_post_title, 
  linked_article 
FROM wp_cpt_combined 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET ('72', REPLACE(REPLACE(habitat_type, '[', ''), ']', ''))
```

Comment: Brilliant. Just as I suspected, just didn't quite get the replace nesting correct. Thank you.

Comment: @user142553 happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by removing the square bracket 
find in set works like Find_in_set(72,'72,73,74') it will return position of 72 i.e 1
while find_in_set(72,'73,72,74') i.e 2
so you can also try to use conditional operator find_in_set(72,'72,73')>0